# Connecting two monitors, projector and video mixer to one computer

Tags: multiple-monitors, projector

I'm in the process of purchasing a presentation software program that requires output two monitors; 1 for Staging and 1 for the Live Presentation.  In addition to this, I will need to output the Live Presentation to a projector and a video mixer.  All of this is connected to 1 computer.  Can you recommend what type of video card(s) I will need?